# Expected loss for regression tree with absolute loss function in case of choosing labels randomly

Tags: optimization, regression, machine-learning, decision-trees

Suppose we have a regression tree (binary). The absolute loss function $L(y,\hat{y})=|y-\hat{y}|$. I know that the optimal prediction that minimizes $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}|y_{i}-\hat{y}|$ is the median of labels: 
$$\hat{y}=\text{median}(y_{1},\dots,y_{n}).$$
I'm curious what happens if instead of using optimal prediction for this leaf we output the label from $y_{1},\dots,y_{n}$ at random what will happen with the expected loss on the training sample?

Comment: Does $\hat{y}$ denote the medium? Normally $\hat{y}$ denotes the 'guessed' value.

Comment: @Max yes, it's guessed value.

Comment: What variable is there to minimize? Because the median seems static.

Comment: @Max Consider a leaf of a binary decision tree which consists of object-label pairs $(x_{1},y_{1}),\dots,(x_{n},y_{n})$. The prediction $\hat{y}$ of this leaf is defined to minimize the loss on the training sample, i.e. $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}L(y_{i}, \hat{y})\rightarrow\min$.

Comment: Thanks, I understand now... sorry for my question.